# Regex doesn't work as I need

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate an account number. It is supposed to have only digits and have 9 or 10 characters.
I tried this:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(id, "[0-9]{9,10}");
```

But this is not working correctly, as it returns true in case the number is "1234567890blah".
Could you please help, as I am not that good with regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to indicate that the digits must be the entire string. Put `^` at the start to indicate that it must be the start of the string and `$` to indicate that it must be the end.

```
return Regex.IsMatch(id, "^[0-9]{9,10}$");
```

See [Regular Expression Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you and others who gave the right answer. It does work.

Answer (score 4):

Modify by using ( Add start and end caracter, ^ and $ caracter)

```
return Regex.IsMatch(id, "^[0-9]{9,10}$");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem with regex.  There are simpler and clearer solutions.

```
string acct = "1234567890";
long temp; 

return (acct.Length == 9 || acct.Length == 10)
    && long.TryParse(acct, out temp);
```

Comment: It's not a "problem with regex", it's regex being used incorrectly. Regex is intentionally a very precise tool.